# Attribute in Python class as default operand for all numerical operations

Tags: python, class

I'd like to define an attribute in a Python class which is to be used in all numerical operations (`__add__`, `__mul__`, etc):

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self, param1, param2):
        self.oper = param1
```

So in the class above, I'd like to use the attribute `oper` in all numerical operations. For example, I'd like to implement the following behavior:

```
>>> Example(1, 2) + Example(3, 4)
4
>>> 3 * Example(2, 10)
6
```

In order to do that, do I need to implement each of the numerical operation functions that I want (`__add__`, `__mul__`, etc), or is there a more concise/Pythonic way of doing that?

Here is some context, if it helps: this class is supposed to hold a few variables (namely, a random variable, like `rv` from scipy.stats, and a dictionary containing some percentiles). If it is called in a numerical operation (say, `2 + Example(3, 10)`), it is supposed to use one of the values in the dictionary as operand in the operation, which is expected to return `float`.

Comment: in `3 * Example(2, 10)` your output is 6, what is the purpose of 10 then?

Comment: Is your question **how** to inherit float? Or whether you **should** inherit float? One has an answer, the other has an opinion.

Comment: @CongMa As far as I understand it, in my example code, __getattribute__ never gets called. It would only be called if I tried accessing the `oper` attribute, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @RobertB My question is how to do what I described in the question. I mentioned inheriting `float` as a possible solution to my question; I have an intuition that, if what I described can be done, it will probably involve inheriting `float` somehow, but that was a guess on my part. I suppose I should make that clearer in my question.

Comment: @dopstar In my actual problem, the `Example` class takes multiple arguments. The `param2` is there only to illustrate that. I'd like to calculate, from the arguments, a number which will be the default operator.

Comment: Do you mean default **operand**?

Comment: @tzaman I do, yes. I'll correct the title. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried implementing the `__add__` method. Did it work?

Comment: @RobertB It did. Implementing each numerical method works fine, but it seems unpythonic. I'd like a more general solution, if possible.

Comment: Since you are being vague about what you really want this class to do, it is hard to comment. Possibly just creating a `__float__` function is what you want. Possibily, the best thing to do is to implement `__add__` and `__radd__`.  For example, what is the type of the `2 + Example(3,10)`? Is it supposed to be a 'float' or an 'Example'? Is the answer the same if you do the math the other way `Example(3,10)+2`? In your example `Example(1, 2) + Example(3, 4)`, is the result of type "Example" or type 'float"? These things matter a lot in the answer. I

Comment: @RobertB Numerical operations on `Example` are supposed to return `float`. So in all your examples, the expected type is `float`. As for the vagueness, I'll try to be more specific: this class is supposed to hold a few variables (namely, a random variable, like `rv` from `scipy.stats`, and a dictionary containing some percentiles). If it is called like `2 + Example(3, 10)`, it is supposed to use one of the values in the dictionary as operand in the sum.

Comment: Last question. Why is `Example` implemented as a class and not a function that returns a float?

Comment: @RobertB Because `Example` is also expected to work as a container for a few values (namely, an `rv`-type attribute and a dictionary).

Comment: operator overloading usually boils down to messing with magic methods in python and that IS pythonic even though most common case is the `__init__` magic method which everyone is comfortable with. What is unpythonic is to call those magic methods yourself (with `__init__` being an exception). So if you really unsure whether you code is pythonic or not, please include it in your question because we cannot try to re-solve the problem you already solved before you came here. And you can see by how many probing questions that details are sketchy.

Comment: @dopstar I don't understand. I haven't solved it. The reason I said that implementing each numerical operation method seems unpythonic is that it would just be one-liners, like `def __add__(self, other): return self.oper + other`, repeated [8 times](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__add__#object.__add__).

Comment: Most classes just expose an attribute or a method for this. Ex: `3 * Example(2,10).value()`. This is very unambiguous. If you really want it to emulate a base type, then yes, I would implement all of those magic methods. Not just `__add__` but also `__radd__` etc.

Comment: @RobertB Yes, I'm starting to think that's the way to go, too. I just wanted to check if the community had a more concise solution. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider casting it to the desired type

```
>>> class Example:
...     def __init__(self, param1, param2):
...         self.param1 = param1
...         self.param2 = param2
...     def __int__(self):
...         return self.param1

>>> 3 * int(Example(2,1))
6
```

Comment: or `__float__` in this case.

Comment: I hadn't tought of that, thank you! In this case, though, I'd have to type cast `Example` to a numerical type every time I do an operation.